# How to convert an Epoch to a OffsetDateTime in Kotlin?

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq, epoch, datetimeoffset

The postgresql `Timestamp with Time Zone` data type needs to be supplied an `OffsetDateTime` when being called using a High level language like Kotlin. 
I could not find a direct method that supports Epoch to OffsetDateTime conversion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
fun convertEpochToOffsetDateTime(epochValue: Long): OffsetDateTime {
  return OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(epochValue, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC), ZoneOffset.UTC)
}
```

Btw, I'm using Jooq for SQL queries using Kotlin. The above works like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

Another way is to go from Long -> Instant -> OffsetDateTime

```
OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(started_at), ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Comment: this does not work, try converting 1613989887 which is "2021-02-22T10:31:27Z".  your code will yield "1970-01-19T16:19:49.887Z"

Comment: Note the difference between seconds and milliseconds from epoc. Your value is seconds from epoc, append three zeros to it and you will get the expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I just found:

```
fun dateFormatter(epoch: Long): String {
        // epoch = 1557954848
        val date = Date(epoch * 1000L)
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
        return sdf.format(date)
        // returned value = "2019-05-15 14:14:08.000000"
}
```